# Meaning and Implications of InternalFormat, Format, and Type parameter for WebGL Textures

Tags: webgl, webgl2

In WebGL calls to `texSubImage2D` and `readPixels` require a `Format` and `Type` parameters. In addition `texSubImage2D` requires an `InternalFormat` parameter.  While it is easy to find documentation about which combinations of these parameters are valid, it is unclear exactly what these parameters mean and how to go about using them efficiently, particularly given that some internal formats can be paired with multiple types e.g.
`R16F`/`HALF_FLOAT` vs `R16F`/`FLOAT` or `GL_R11F_G11F_B10F`/`FLOAT` vs `GL_R11F_G11F_B10F`/`GL_UNSIGNED_INT_10F_11F_11F_REV` (where the notation I am using is `InternalFormat`/`Type`)

Also both of these API calls can be used in combination with a `pixels` parameter that can be a `TypedArray` -- it this case it is unclear which choices of `TypedArray` are valid for a given `InternalFormat`/`Format`/`Type` combo (and which choice is optimal in terms of avoiding casting)

For instance, is it true that the internal memory used by the GPU per texel is determined solely by the `InternalFormat`  -- either in an implementation dependent way (e.g. `WebGL1` `unsized` formats) or, for some newly added `InternalFormat`s in  `WegGL2`, a fully specified way.

Are the `Format` and `Type` parameters related primarily to how data is marshalled into and out of `ArrayBuffers`?  For instance, if I use `GL_R11F_G11F_B10F`/`GL_UNSIGNED_INT_10F_11F_11F_REV`
does this mean I should be passing `texSubImage2D` an `Uint32Array` with each element of the array having its bits carefully twiddled in `javascript` whereas if I use `GL_R11F_G11F_B10F`/`Float` then I should use a `Float32Array` with three times number of elements as the prior case, and WebGL will handle the bit twiddling for me?  Does WebGL try to check that the `TypedArray` I have passed is consistent with the `Format`/`Type` I have chosen or does it operate directly on the underlying `ArrayBuffer`?  Could I have used a `Float64Array` in the last instance?  And what to do about `HALF_FLOAT`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like bulk of the question can be answered by referring to section 3.7.6 Texture Objects of the [WebGL2 Spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0).  In particular the info in the table found in the documentation for `texImage2D` which clarifies which `TypedArray` is required for each `Type`:

```
TypedArray  WebGL Type 
----------  ----------
Int8Array   BYTE
Uint8Array  UNSIGNED_BYTE
Int16Array  SHORT
Uint16Array UNSIGNED_SHORT
Uint16Array UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5
Uint16Array UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1
Uint16Array UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4
Int32Array  INT
Uint32Array UNSIGNED_INT
Uint32Array UNSIGNED_INT_5_9_9_9_REV
Uint32Array UNSIGNED_INT_2_10_10_10_REV
Uint32Array UNSIGNED_INT_10F_11F_11F_REV
Uint32Array UNSIGNED_INT_24_8
Uint16Array HALF_FLOAT
Float32Array    FLOAT
```

My guess is that

- `InternalFormat` determines how much GPU memory is used to store the texture
- `Format` and `Type` governs how data is marshalled into/ out of the texture and javascript.
- `Type` determines what type of TypedArray must be used
- `Format` plus the `pixelStorei` parameters (section 6.10) determine how many elements the TypedArray will need and which elements will actually by used (will things be tightly packed, will some rows be padded etc)

Todo:
Workout details for

- encoding/decoding some of the more obscure `Type` values to and from javascript.
- calculating typed array size requirement and stride info given `Type`, `Format`, and `pixelStorei` parameters